# Periodic functions on groups

Tags: ca.classical-analysis-and-odes, invariant-theory, periodic-functions

I'll give you some context: We can say that a (classic) periodic function $f:\mathbb{R}\rightarrow\mathbb{R}$ with period $\omega$ is an invariant function under the cyclic subgroup $G=\langle\omega\rangle\leq (\mathbb{R},+)$ since $f(g+x)=f(x),$ for all $g\in G$. If we consider $G=\langle\omega\rangle\leq (\mathbb{R}^+,\cdot)$, then a periodic function $f:\mathbb{R^+}\rightarrow\mathbb{R}$ satisfies $f(g\cdot x)=f(x)$, for all $g\in G$. Such functions appear for example, as solutions to some Euler's ODEs. I'm looking for references in order to study such functions and related ODEs for more general groups and hopefully unify the preceding two examples (for instance, if the theory over $G=GL(2,\mathbb{R})$ and its subgroups was known, I'd be very happy). When I look for periodic functions over groups I get almost periodic functions on groups and when I look for invariant functions I get $G$-invariant functions for non-cyclic groups and automorphic forms, which is not exactly what I'm looking for. Thanks in advance.

Comment: This sounds as *group representations* and *special functions*.